# Is there some web where we can use LaTeX?

Tags: editors, online

I often read math books and papers and want to keep some useful theorems or proofs in one place. It is very convenient to find them when I need them someday.

Now I want to find some webs where I can use LaTeX to write down those math results which interest me.

Does anybody know such webs?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not very clear to me what exactly you are looking for. If you want to get theorems or proofs as LaTeX code, you could have a look at some [Wikipedia articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_proofs) (in the *Edit* section) which uses LaTeX syntax for math formulas

Comment: Just create an account with overleaf.com, it should provide what you are looking for.

Comment: Click here: https://www.overleaf.com/

Comment: Thank you,  siracusa and Uwe Ziegenhagen. I found overleaf.com is very useful.

Comment: [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is a great choice for people who need LaTeX and math/science.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to type math formulas only, I suggest using [CodeCogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). On the other hand, if you want to create `LaTeX` documents online, [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) is the best choice.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly.

If it is a site on which you can upload your own mathematical works in a public way, then you can create a [GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/).

On this page, you can create a real static website with [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/). You can use [Mathjax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) to write LateX formulas [with Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987992/using-mathjax-with-jekyll).

Not having created a site on a GitHub page and not using Mathjax, I can't say any more.